Image not loading on local site I made
Using Chrome Version 109.0.5414.120 (Official Build) (32-bit) because it is the last version for Windows 7 (I believe).
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Vagamond Detective From The Wild West</TITLE>
  <H3>Vagamond Detective From The Wild West</H3>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
  <audio src="1-33. Jake Marshall ~ Vagamond Detective From The Wild West.flac", controls=pause, play>
  <img src="Jake Marshall.png", alt="Jake Marshall">
 </BODY>
</HTML>

When I inspect I see no issues. All files are in the same folder, including the HTML file, so there is nothing wrong with the path.
Expected image to load. It didn't.

I have noticed in audio and img src attribute, there is space in the names of files. Try renaming the files and removing the space. For example, Jake_Marshall.png, 1_33_Jake_Marshall_Vagamond_Detective_From_The_Wild_West.flac

Tried it, didn't work

  <img src="./Jake_Marshall.png", alt="Jake Marshall">```

can u try the above code. I'm assuming the file names are updated with underscore.

Still not working :(

Check the HTML with w3org. There are weird stuff like missing end tags and commas between attributes etc. You really should make sure the file names are simple and the HTML is valid - this isn't controls=pause, play

The attribute is controls and it does not take prameters

After debugging your code I found out your audio tag is not closed.
Also the controls attribute was incorrect.
Try this:
<audio src="1-33. Jake Marshall ~ Vagamond Detective From The Wild West.flac" controls></audio>


I noticed a couple of issues in your code.

You have added <h3> inside <head>, which is wrong.
You didn't close <audio> element.
Space in src value.
The attribute controls does not take parameters
Random commas in the tags

You wrote element names in all capital <HTML>, <BODY> etc. Try using all lowercase to reduce mistake chances <html>, <body>. Also rename the files and remove spaces. Try using single name and if it is necessary to use multiple words then use camelCase or underscore '_'.
Here is the updated code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vagamond Detective From The Wild West</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Vagamond Detective From The Wild West</h3>
  <audio src="1_33_Jake_Marshall_Vagamond_Detective_From_The_Wild_West.flac" controls></audio>
  <img src="Jake_Marshall.png" alt="Jake Marshall">
</body>
</html>


I have analyzed your code and have some advice:

Tags are written in lowercase letters.
There should be no <h3> in the  section.
Tags must be closed. In this case, </audio>
It will be better if the structure of your project is more organized. The project folder, which contains html, css, and other files, as well as a folder for images and a folder for sounds. then the entry will look like this  <img src="image/you_file_name.jpg" />
try to avoid names with spaces. For this use "_" in your case Jake_Marshall.png

A more correct spelling would look like this:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vagamond Detective From The Wild West</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Vagamond Detective From The Wild West</h3>
        <audio src="1_33_Jake_Marshall_Vagamond_Detective_From_The_Wild_West.flac", controls=pause, play></audio>
        <img src="Jake_Marshall.png" alt="Jake Marshall" />
    </body>
</html>

